# Facebook "like" integration - Is it possible to link individual page "likes" back to an aggregated like count my company Facebook page?

Tags: facebook, facebook-like

We have a [Company facebook page](http://www.facebook.com/forkie.website) and we the individual pages of our [Portfolio](http://forkie.com.au/portfolio/zoggs+australia) have Facebook "Like" buttons on them.

The problem is, when a user clicks on the "like" button in our Portfolio it doesn't update the "like" count on our Company facebook page.

Does anyone know:

1. If this can be done; and
2. If so, how to do it

P.S. - we are aware we can point the href section of the porfolio "like" button to our Company Facebook page to acheive something similar, but this only allows users to "like" one URL, instead of allowing them to "like" individual project pages in our portfolio.

Many thanks for any light you can shed on this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Doing this automatically isn't possible.

One of options is listening for **edge.create** [event](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.Event.subscribe/) and bring attention of users providing em with ability to like your "company page".

Comment: Thanks Juicy Scripter. Not the answer I wanted to hear, but an answer non-the-less. :(

Comment: It's [not even possible to merge the likes of your URL with those of your fan page](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9984330/merging-a-websites-likes-into-a-facebook-page?lq=1).