# Merging a website's likes into a Facebook page

Tags: html, facebook, facebook-like

We launched our website before we started our Facebook page, and it got something like 2k likes. But those likes, obviously, were for our .com domain itself. Now our like button points at our new Facebook page instead, which has 161 likes.

We want to "claim" the likes from our .com domain name under the banner of our Facebook page.

This Facebook FAQ seems to be related: https://www.facebook.com/help/?faq=249601088403018#I-have-two-Facebook-Pages-for-the-same-thing.-Can-I-merge-them

2 problems though:

- We're talking about merging a website into a Facebook page, not a page and a page
- The FAQ states that the page with fewer likes will be destroyed. Obviously, we want to KEEP our page! This is how we're communicating with users.

Thanks!

Comment: This is a question for Facebook, contact them.

Comment: We have the exact question and I was just thinking of asking it too! Wild that you asked this just four hours ago.

Comment: Marko, how do you recommend contacting them? i.e. What channel would you use?

Comment: Our social media manager contacted them... I'm not sure what's going to come of it. They have a specific contact detail page for developers: https://developers.facebook.com/policy/contact/ ... I'll report back if we hear anything. We've already tried "claiming" the .com domain name for insights, but that didn't really help (eg, likers of the .com did not become likers of the Page).

Comment: did anything ever come out of this?