# Facebook Like Button: Unify a Url & a Facebook Page

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-like

In [Facebook docs](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/) it says:

```
Can I link the Like button to my Facebook page?
Yes. Simply specify the URL of your Facebook page in
the href parameter of the button.
```

My problem is that I don't want the Facebook page to be the target of the 'like'.
So currently, the like button on my site attributes the likes to the root domain 'http://example.com/', which is what I want.

This has got many more likes than the facebook page 'http://facebook.com/examplecompage'

Is there a way to make the likes on my facebook page contribute towards the root domain likes?

Comment: as far as i know its not possible

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9984330/merging-a-websites-likes-into-a-facebook-page

Answer (score 2):

That is not possible, since they are treated as 2 different objects.
And just to clarify, the documentation on the Facebook developer site is referring to the Like button that you create to be displayed on your site, not the Like button you get on Facebook automatically when you create a page.

Comment: Not possible still, [despite numerous requests from users](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9984330/merging-a-websites-likes-into-a-facebook-page)